# Removing Zeros in a list of vectors

Tags: r

I have a list of 36 vectors containing sorted integers, including lots of zeros.

```
List of 36
 $ R11: int [1:361] 241 240 239 349 238 237 236 235 234 233 ...
 $ R12: int [1:361] 287 286 285 350 284 283 282 281 280 279 ...
```

I do not know how remove the zeros from the vectors. I tried `lapply (list, list(list x!=0)`, but this wasnt successful. Thank you.

Comment: Try: `lapply(list,function(x) x[x!=0])`

Comment: Something similar to @vck i was trying `lapply(list, function(x) x[which(x!=0)])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `l` is your list then

```
lapply(l, function(x) {x[x!=0]})
```

might work (but you can end up with list elements of different lengths). Calling your list `list` might not be the best option

Comment: This is vck's comment.

Comment: yeah. We must have typed the answers just about at the same time. Move the answer credit to him

Comment: Yes, 2 minutes difference.

Comment: @Pascal, the answer box is a little bit further down from where vck decided to post their "answer" :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto It is vck decision.

Comment: So too is it ekstroem's decision to post an answer in the correct place.

Comment: I agree with @Ananda, especially since it's a sort of trivial answer, i.e. not a highly customized concept that must have been copied from a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Quick and easy zero remover is: `if(length(which(x==0)!=0)) x[-which(x==0)]`