# Cut elements from the beginning and end of an R vector

Tags: r

For time series analysis I handle data that often contains leading and trailing zero elements. In this example, there are 3 zeros at the beginning an 2 at the end. I want to get rid of these elements, and filter for the contents in the middle (that also may contain zeros)

```
vec <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0)
```

I did this by looping from the beginning and end, and masking out the unwanted elements.

```
mask <- rep(TRUE, length(vec))

# from begin
i <- 1
while(vec[i] == 0 && i <= length(vec)) {
  mask[i] <- FALSE
  i <- i+1
}

# from end
i <- length(vec)
while(i >= 1 && vec[i] == 0) {
  mask[i] <- FALSE
  i <- i-1
}

cleanvec <- vec[mask]
cleanvec
[1] 1 2 0 3 4
```

This works, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this, avoiding the loops.

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581950/removing-zeros-in-a-list-of-vectors

Comment: This is referred to lists, not vectors; furthermore, it removes all zeros in the list elements, whereas here the question asks for removing zeros at the beginning and at the end of the vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
vec[ min(which(vec != 0)) : max(which(vec != 0)) ]
```

Basically the `which(vec != 0)` part gives the positions of the numbers that are different from 0, and then you take the *min* and *max* of them.

Comment: good solution, but this will cause an error if vec consists only of zeros.

Comment: You are right, maybe you can set an if statement to check whether that conditions occurs.

Answer (score 0):

We could use the `range` and `Reduce` to get the sequence

```
vec[Reduce(`:`, range(which(vec != 0)))]
#[1] 1 2 0 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the `cumsum` forward and backward of `abs(vec)` and keep only elements > 0.  if it were known that all elements of `vec` were non-negative, as in the question, then we could optionally omit `abs`.

```
vec[cumsum(abs(vec)) > 0 & rev(cumsum(rev(abs(vec)))) > 0]
## [1] 1 2 0 3 4
```